# fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https' BitBucket Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: git, bitbucket, ubuntu-16.04

Hello I'm using bitbucket along with git to manage a project. I tried to follow their mini-tutorial:

```
 mkdir /path/to/your/projectcd /path/to/your/project
 git init
 git remote add origin https://jhaik@bitbucket.org/wod123/wod2-test.git
```

> ```
> echo "wod" >> contributors.txt
> git add contributors.txt
> git commit -m "Initial commit with contributors"
> git push -u origin master
> ```

but I get `fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'`

I tried to reinstall git but I can't find a solution.

How can I fix this please?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and my Git version is 2.9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh finally it seems like when i installed git using apt-get it didnt compiled with curl and expat ! installing and compilling it manually (./configure --with-curl --with-expat) solved my problem !